# Replace Illegal XML characters with value from table Oracle PL\SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to check all text fields in a Database schema for any Illegal XML characters and replace them with a predefined set of acceptable values. This is to form part of a Data transformation rule, than can be called from other functions. So this function could be asked to called over a billion times on our dataset, so I need it to operate really efficiently.

i.e.  &  =  AND , 
' = APOS

An example of what needs to be achieved by the function should be:

`Update sometable set somefield = functioncall('f&re'd');`

should result in 
somefield having the value of ' fANDreAPOSd'

This is to carried out by a generic type PL/SQL function that takes an input of a text field and iterate through that field and replace all illegal values.

I have had a look at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2612348048

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/removing-un-wanted-text-from-strings-in-oracle/

For some ideas, but I have my concerns over efficiency and the flexibility of these soltuions.

The way the client wants to handle the solution is to have a table configured to contain an illegal character and it's prefered replacement. The function then uses the values selected from this table to preform the replacements.

Answer (score 2):

well, not exactly what you want, but consider this:

```
create type xmltest is object (s clob);

select XMLTYPE.createXml(xmltest('a& and ''')) from dual;

XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(XMLTEST('A&'''))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<XMLTEST>
  <S>a&amp; &apos;</S>
</XMLTEST>
```

However the [list of predefined of XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) is quite small, so there wouldn't be an issue replacing them with `replace`

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If this is because of XML I'll support hal9000 - you should let Oracle do that for you. E.g. [XML functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions002.htm#CIHGFCGD) do it automatically:

```
SQLPLUS> set define off
SQLPLUS> select xmlelement("e", 'foo & bar <> bar "hemingway''s"') from dual;

XMLELEMENT("E",'FOO&BAR<>BAR"HEMINGWAY''S"')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<e>foo &amp; bar &lt;&gt; bar &quot;hemingway&apos;s&quot;</e>
```